# How to display multiple images in jsp using IOUtils package in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc, imageview

I am getting the one image in jsp by using OutputStream.So is switched to IOUtils, in that  want to display all images from DB in Jsp but am (Getting all images in a binary format i need to display it in a image) please

Answer (score 0):

JSP is a part of view layer, so you should not insert any Java code there. Only HTML with JSP tags. I suggest to modify your JSP page and use `img` tags for showing images. To get this images you need to write separate servlet which will serve images.

See example here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Comment: Ya its possible ...but i want to write it in a IOUtils method ...can u tell the solution for this ?

Comment: How it possible when we retrived the image from the DB not from any folder.

Comment: Link bellow also highlights this point: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html#FileServletServingFromDatabase